# How to convert below code in scrollable view?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fit pie chart, bar graph and line graph in the same screen in scrollable view 
I want to display multiple graphs in a single screen in scrollable view 
I used flexible() widget that fitted the graph in a single screen then I tried ListView and SingleChildScrollView but it's not working
Below are the codes of whatever I tried

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:pie_chart/pie_chart.dart';
import 'DonutPieChart.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  HomePage({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

Map<String, double> dataMap = new Map();

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{
  List<charts.Series<Pollution, String>> _seriesData;
  List<charts.Series<Electricity1, String>> _seriesPieData;
  List<charts.Series<Vehicles,int>> _seriesLineData;
  List<charts.Series<Electricity, String>>_seriesPieData1;

  TabController _tabController;
  ScrollController _scrollViewController;

  int _counter = 0;

  _generateData() {
    var data1 = [
      new Pollution('June',3),
      new Pollution('July',1),
      new Pollution('August',5),
    ];
    var data2 = [
      new Pollution('June', 1),
      new Pollution('July',2),
      new Pollution('August',4),
    ];

    var data3 = [
      new Pollution('June', 5),
      new Pollution('July',3),
      new Pollution('August',3),
    ];

    var piedata = [
      new Electricity1('Renewable Onsite', 8),
      new Electricity1('Renewable Wheeled', 10),
      new Electricity1('Purchased Grid', 15),
    ];

    var piedata1 = [
      new Electricity('Renewable', 18, Color(0xfffdbe19)),
      new Electricity('Purchased Grid', 15, Color(0xff990099)),
    ];

    var linedata = [
      new Vehicles(2, 56),
      new Vehicles(4, 55),
      new Vehicles(6, 60),
      new Vehicles(8, 61),
      new Vehicles(10, 70),
    ];
    var linedata1 = [
      new Vehicles(2, 46),
      new Vehicles(4, 45),
      new Vehicles(6, 50),
      new Vehicles(8, 51),
      new Vehicles(10, 60),
    ];

    var linedata2 = [
      new Vehicles(2, 24),
      new Vehicles(4, 25),
      new Vehicles(6, 40),
      new Vehicles(8, 45),
      new Vehicles(10, 60),
    ];

      final data = [
        new LinearSales(0, 100),
        new LinearSales(1, 75),
        new LinearSales(2, 25),
        new LinearSales(3, 5),
      ];

    _seriesData.add(
      charts.Series(
        id:'LPG-Cooking',
        domainFn: (Pollution pollution, _) => pollution.place,
        measureFn: (Pollution pollution, _) => pollution.quantity,
        data: data1,
      ),
    );

    _seriesData.add(
      charts.Series(
        id:'Diesel',
        domainFn: (Pollution pollution, _) => pollution.place,
        measureFn: (Pollution pollution, _) => pollution.quantity,
        data: data2,
      ),
    );

    _seriesData.add(
      charts.Series(
        id:'LPG-lab',
        domainFn: (Pollution pollution, _) => pollution.place,
        measureFn: (Pollution pollution, _) => pollution.quantity,
        data: data3,
      ),
    );

    _seriesPieData.add(
      charts.Series(
        id:'Pollution',
        domainFn: (Electricity1 e, _) => e.emission,
        measureFn: (Electricity1 e, _) => e.emission_value,
        data: piedata,
        // Set a label accessor to control the text of the arc label.
        labelAccessorFn: (Electricity1 e, _) => '${e.emission}: ${e.emission_value}',
      ),
    );

    _seriesPieData1.add(
      charts.Series(
        id:'Pollution',
        domainFn: (Electricity e, _) => e.emission,
        measureFn: (Electricity e, _) => e.emission_value,
        colorFn: (Electricity e, _) =>
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(e.colorval),
        data: piedata1,
        // Set a label accessor to control the text of the arc label.
        labelAccessorFn: (Electricity e, _) => '${e.emission}: ${e.emission_value}',
      ),
    );

    _seriesLineData.add(
      charts.Series(
        id: 'Two wheeler',
        data: linedata,
        domainFn: (Vehicles v, _) => v.month,
        measureFn: (Vehicles v, _) => v.emissions,
      ),
    );
    _seriesLineData.add(
      charts.Series(
        colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xff0277BD)),
        id: 'Three wheeler',
        data: linedata1,
        domainFn: (Vehicles v, _) => v.month,
        measureFn: (Vehicles v, _) => v.emissions,
      ),
    );
    _seriesLineData.add(
      charts.Series(
        colorFn: (__, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xff01579D)),
        id: 'Four wheeler',
        data: linedata2,
        domainFn: (Vehicles v, _) => v.month,
        measureFn: (Vehicles v, _) => v.emissions,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _seriesData = List<charts.Series<Pollution, String>>();
    _seriesPieData = List<charts.Series<Electricity1, String>>();
    _seriesLineData = List<charts.Series<Vehicles,int>>();
    _seriesPieData1= List<charts.Series<Electricity, String>>();
    _generateData();

    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Flutter", () => 5);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("React", () => 3);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Xamarin", () => 2);
    dataMap.putIfAbsent("Ionic", () => 2);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _scrollViewController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var dpc = DonutPieChart.withSampleData();
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
            body:Center(
              child:ListView(
              //child:Column(
                //children: [
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 30.0,
                    child: Text(
                      'Direct Emissions by lpg-cooking, lpg-lab  and diesel (in kg)',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),
                  Flexible( flex: 5,
                    child:
                    Card(
                            child: charts.BarChart(
                        _seriesData,
                        animate: true,
                        barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked,
                        behaviors: [new charts.SeriesLegend()],
                        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      ),
                            ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 30.0,
                    child:Text(
                      'CO2 produced by electricity',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex:5,
                    child:
                    Card(
                      child:Stack(
                        children:<Widget>[
                          Container(
                            //color: Colors.blue,
                            height: 300.0,
                            width: 300.0,
                            child: dpc,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            // color: Colors.blue,
                            height: 300.0,
                            width: 300.0,
                            child: PieChart(dataMap: dataMap, showLegends: false,),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 30.0,
                    child:Text(
                      'CO2 in kg produced by vehicles',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex:5,
                    child:
                    Card(
                      child: charts.LineChart(
                          _seriesLineData,
                          defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(
                              includeArea: true, stacked: true),
                          animate: true,
                          animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                          behaviors: [
                            new charts.SeriesLegend(),
                            new charts.ChartTitle('Months',
                                behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
                                titleOutsideJustification:charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
                          ]
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        ),
        ),
      );
  }
}

class Pollution {
  String place;
  int quantity;

  Pollution(this.place, this.quantity);
}

class Vehicles {
  int month;
  double emissions;

  Vehicles(this.month, this.emissions);
}

class Electricity{
  String emission;
  double emission_value;
  Color colorval;
  Electricity(this.emission,this.emission_value,this.colorval);
}

class Electricity1{
  String emission;
  double emission_value;

  Electricity1(this.emission,this.emission_value);
}
```

```
DonutPieChart.dart file 

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

class DonutPieChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  DonutPieChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [PieChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory DonutPieChart.withSampleData() {
    return new DonutPieChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.PieChart(seriesList,
        animate: animate,
        // Configure the width of the pie slices to 60px. The remaining space in
        // the chart will be left as a hole in the center.
        defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(arcWidth: 60));
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales(0, 100),
      new LinearSales(1, 75),
      new LinearSales(2, 25),
      new LinearSales(3, 5),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample linear data type.
class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;

  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Comment: Can you post whole code here, right now not found some global variable you define.

Comment: Just wrap your Scaffold's `Column` widget  with `SingleChildScrollView` and you're good to go.

Comment: Okay will post whole code

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

> A scrollable list of widgets arranged linearly.

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body:Center(
          child:
//          Column(
//          children: [
          ListView(
            children: <Widget>[


              SizedBox(height: 30.0,
                child: Text(
                  'Direct Emissions by lpg-cooking, lpg-lab  and diesel (in kg)',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ),
              Flexible( flex: 5,
                child:
                Card(
                  child: charts.BarChart(
                    _seriesData,
                    animate: true,
                    barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked,
                    behaviors: [new charts.SeriesLegend()],
                    animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 30.0,
                child:Text(
                  'CO2 produced by electricity',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex:5,
                child:
                Card(
                  child:Stack(
                    children:<Widget>[
                      Container(
                        //color: Colors.blue,
                        height: 300.0,
                        width: 300.0,
                        child: dpc,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        // color: Colors.blue,
                        height: 300.0,
                        width: 300.0,
                        child: PieChart(dataMap: dataMap, showLegends: false,),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 30.0,
                child:Text(
                  'CO2 in kg produced by vehicles',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ),
              Flexible(
                flex:5,
                child:
                Card(
                  child: charts.LineChart(
                      _seriesLineData,
                      defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(
                          includeArea: true, stacked: true),
                      animate: true,
                      animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      behaviors: [
                        new charts.SeriesLegend(),
                        new charts.ChartTitle('Months',
                            behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
                            titleOutsideJustification:charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
                      ]
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `Column` inside a `SingleChildScrollView` and use `Container`s with the desired height instead of `Flexible`.
Don't forget to set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to your `Column`.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var dpc = DonutPieChart.withSampleData();
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30.0,
                  child: Text(
                    'Direct Emissions by lpg-cooking, lpg-lab  and diesel (in kg)',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  child: charts.BarChart(
                    _seriesData,
                    animate: true,
                    barGroupingType: charts.BarGroupingType.stacked,
                    behaviors: [charts.SeriesLegend()],
                    animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30.0,
                  child: Text(
                    'CO2 produced by electricity',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  width: 300,
                  child: Card(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(child: dpc),
                        Container(child: dpc),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30.0,
                  child: Text(
                    'CO2 in kg produced by vehicles',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  child: charts.LineChart(_seriesLineData,
                      defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(
                          includeArea: true, stacked: true),
                      animate: true,
                      animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                      behaviors: [
                        charts.SeriesLegend(),
                        charts.ChartTitle('Months',
                            behaviorPosition: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
                            titleOutsideJustification:
                                charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
                      ]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I did it but then scrollable view is there but graph is not displayed on the screen